# Creating an indicator function in a neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I am working on implementing the loss function of the Yolo version 2 object detection network and building from the construction notebook in the Wolfram Neural Network repository [Yolo Version 2](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/YOLO-V2-Trained-on-MS-COCO-Data_1) so I can train it for a specialised detection task. The loss function is quite complicated, I can see how to implement almost all of it but I'm stuck with an indicator function implementation.

During training indicator functions are used to set the maximum value in a tensor to 1 and other values to zero (in the Yolo network it is an higher rank tensor) but the problem comes down to this, how to implement the following (a sort of `indexmax` or `argmax` function)

`{1,2,1,4,2}` => `{0,0,0,1,0}`

There are many ways of doing this with built-in functions but the problem I'm stuck with is how to do it with the functionality available in the neural network framework.
In the snippet below, the Position function is **not** available (that I can find) in the neural net framework.

```
vec = {1,2,1,4,2};
pos = Position[vec, Max[vec]]//Flatten (*this can't be directly implemented in the NN framework*)
UnitVectorLayer[5,"Input"-> "Integer"][pos]
```

This produces `{0.,0.,0.,1.,0.} (*the output I'm after*)`

In Keras there is an 'argmax' function that does something like this. Other functionality like `ReplicateLayer` and related functions can then be used to construct the object needed, this bit isn't where the problem is.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this in the MMA neural network framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can construct an IndexMaxLayer using the existing layers, like so:

```
indexMaxLayer[] := NetGraph[{
   "max" -> AggregationLayer[Max, 1],
   "repl" -> ReplicateLayer[Automatic],
   "switch" -> ThreadingLayer[If[#1 != #2, 0., 1.] &]
   }, {
   "max" -> "repl",
   {NetPort@"Input", "repl"} -> "switch"
   }]

indexMaxLayer[][{1,2,1,4,2}]

> {0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}
```

This is getting the `max`imum value in the input vector, `repl`icating that value to be the same dimensions as the input vector, and then `switch`ing the input layer to 0 or 1 if it does or doesn't match the `max` value.

This is extendable to multiple dimensions if you change the second argument to `AggregationLayer`, although there are multiple different behaviours you might want in that case (max per level or max over the entire matrix, for instance).

Comment: That's neat, thanks very much! I'd looked thoroughly through the documentation at the functions supported by ThreadingLayer, AggregationLayer etc and hadn't thought of experimenting with others (e.g. If) to see if they work.

Comment: No problem! Please consider marking this answer as accepted if it solved your problem!

Comment: I'll leave it a day or so before accepting it

Comment: Isn't there a way to compute the `len` from the input layer without having the user to explicitly supply it?

Comment: I don't know for sure! It certainly seems like it should be possible, since so many of the built-in layers have the ability to do this, but I didn't find anything that would calculate the dimensions for the ReplicateLayer.

Comment: Aha, `Automatic`. Updating my answer now

Comment: Yup that was what I meant, nice :)

Comment: @LucaAmerio It works perfectly for me on my local 11.3 install and in a cloud notebook. Perhaps you could open a question with the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: @CarlLange I discovered that in order for this to work, you need version 11.3.5 of the NN Paclet. You can check your version doing `Lookup["Version"]@PacletInformation["NeuralNetworks"]`. Version 11.3 comes with version 11.3.4, so this code doesn't run. To update it, you need to run `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
PacletUpdate /@ {"NeuralNetworks", "MXNetLink"}`