# Random sampling of a discrete distribution in NetGraph

Tags: random, neural-networks, sampling

Within a NetGraph I would like to use the output of a softmax layer, interpreted as a probability distribution, to sample a "next token". Since this is done inside an RNN structure, I cannot do this outside of the NetGraph. However, I have not found any reference as to how this might be done inside a NetGraph.

I would like to construct a NetGraph layer which takes as input an array `p={p1,p2,...,pn}` where `Sum[p]=1`, so that we can regard p as a probability distribution on `Range[n]`. The output of the layer should be an integer in `Range[n]` constructed by randomly sampling `Range[n]` according to the probabilities `{p1,p2,...,pn}`.

Comment: Welcome to mathematica.stackexchange.com! It's not clear to me how this is related to random number generation in `NetGraph`s. Can you clarify with some more details in your question - especially with examples, if you can?

Comment: Don't worry! As it is, though, your title doesn't seem to mesh with the text of your question, and more context would be useful for any potential answerer. In any case you might want to look at the `NetDecoder` documentation, specifically for Tokens. Or perhaps the documentation for `SoftmaxLayer`.

Comment: I would like to construct a NetGraph layer which takes as input an array p={p1,p2,...,pn} where Sum[p]=1, so that we can regard p as a probability distribution on Range[n]. The output of the layer should be an integer in Range[n] constructed by randomly sampling Range[n] according to the probabilities {p1,p2,...,pn}.

Comment: I can see how a "Token" NetDecoder would do the job. As I am building an RNN structure using the NetFoldOperator, I will check whether NetDecoder can be part of the network being "folded". Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it will. Please add more to your question so I, and other answerers, have a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps the title should have been "Random sampling of a discrete distribution in NetGraph". Apols.

Comment: Ok. Will come back with fuller example. Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I didn't see your comment with extra information. I've added it to your question and changed your title like you suggested (I agree that it's a better title).

Comment: Does `AttentionLayer` do what you're looking for?

Comment: I've not used `NetGraph` but to get a randomly selected integer based on the probabilities `p={p1,p2,...,pn}`, you can use a variety of ways: 
 (1) `Position[RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[1, p], 1][[1]], 1][[1, 
  1]]`, (2) `RandomSample[p -> Range[Length[p]], 1][[1]]`.

Comment: @JimB Unfortunately, that functionality isn't available within the Neural Network framework and you must build it using the `?*Layer` building blocks.

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks.  Just another example of the many capabilities of *Mathematica* that I have no idea about.

Comment: There is an experimental, undocumented layer called `RandomElementwiseLayer` which may do what you're looking for, but unfortunately I don't have details of how to use it.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this, although it's a bit hacky. It relies on the following fact. Suppose `{g1,g2,...,gn}` are n samples from a Gumbel distribution. Let `z = {Log[p1]+g1, Log[p2]+g2, ..., Log[pn]+gn}`. Then `argmax(z)` is a random sample from `Range[n]` according to the probabilities `{p1,p2,...,pn}`. Note also that I wasn't able to generate the Gumbel samples inside the net, so I have to feed them in as an input. Obviously every time you call the net, you need to pass in a new sample.

I borrowed the `argMaxLayer` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/creating-an-indicator-function-in-a-neural-network) (thanks Carl!). I had to modify slightly to output an integer rather than one-hot.

Here's the full code :

```
argMaxLayer[n_] := NetGraph[{
   "max" -> AggregationLayer[Max, 1],
   "repl" -> ReplicateLayer[Automatic],
   "switch" -> ThreadingLayer[If[#1 != #2, 0., 1.] &],
   "argMax" -> ConstantTimesLayer["Scaling" -> Range[n]],
   "sum" -> AggregationLayer[Total, 1]},
  {NetPort["Input"] -> "max", 
   "max" -> "repl",
   {NetPort["Input"], "repl"} -> "switch",
   "switch" -> "argMax",
   "argMax" -> "sum"}]

n = 4;
input = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25};
gumbel = -Log[-Log[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 4]]];
data = <|"Input" -> input, "Gumbel" -> gumbel|>;
sampleDiscDistLayer = 
  NetGraph[{"Plus" -> Plus, "Log" -> Log, "ArgMax" -> argMaxLayer[n]}, 
   {NetPort["Input"] -> "Log", 
    {"Log", NetPort["Gumbel"], "Log"} -> "Plus",
    "Plus" -> "ArgMax"}];
sampleDiscDistLayer[data]
```

Repeated calls will uniformly sample integers from `Range[n]`. Just change the `input` probabilities to get different discrete distributions on `Range[n]`.

(And apologies for answering my own question as someone else - the UX for this site is very confusing. Think I deleted my profile or something weird)