# Neural network layer for vector normalization

Tags: neural-networks

We have a neural network that returns a vector $v$ with length $n$.
However, these results $v_i$ must be normalized to unity so that their sum $\sum_{i=1} ^{n} v_i=1$. It must be done inside the network to make its training go well.

Which kind of layer can do something like:

1. Take a vector $v$ with length $n$
2. Calculate the sum $S$ of all components $v_i$ of the vector $v$ 
   $$S=\sum_{i=1} ^{n} v_i$$
   (its total)
3. Divide all the components $v_i$ of the vector $v$ by the calculated sum $S$
   $$v_i '=v_i/S $$
4. Return the new vector $v'=(v_i ')_{i=1} ^n$ with the same length $n$.

The sum can be obtained by `SummationLayer[]` operating on the entire vector $v$. Division could be obtained by `ElementwiseLayer[(#/S)&]`. But how do you deliver the divisor (sum) $S$ from `SummationLayer` to `ElementwiseLayer`?

Maybe there is another way to achieve this normalization ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build this function yourself using `SummationLayer`, `ReplicateLayer` and `ThreadingLayer`.

```
v = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}

normalizeLayer = NetGraph[{
   SummationLayer[],
   ReplicateLayer[Automatic],
   ThreadingLayer[#1/#2 &]
   }, {NetPort@"Input" -> 1 -> 2, {NetPort@"Input", 2} -> 3}]

normalizeLayer[v]
```

> ```
> {0.0555556, 0.111111, 0.222222, 0.277778, 0.333333}
> ```

That is, sum the input, replicate the sum `Automatic`ally to have the same dimensions as the input, and divide the input by it.

(In fact, the `ReplicateLayer[Automatic]` gets its dimensions from `ThreadingLayer` - Wolfram Language takes care of resolving these dimensions for you. The `ThreadingLayer` knows that it needs dimensions that are the same as its first input, and asks the `ReplicateLayer` to replicate its input to those dimensions. It's very handy.)

`SoftmaxLayer` is very related here:

```
SoftmaxLayer[][v]
```

> ```
> {0.00440888, 0.0119846, 0.0885547, 0.240717, 0.654335}
> ```

But as you can see, the results are slightly different - `SoftmaxLayer` doesn't do exactly what you're looking for (it normalizes the exponential of the input, rather than the raw input). In both cases the output sums to 1.

To build a `SoftmaxLayer` from scratch, you can modify the above `normalizeLayer` very slightly, to get the sum of the exponential and dividing the exponential of the input by it:

```
ourSoftmaxLayer = NetGraph[{
   ElementwiseLayer[Exp@# &],
   SummationLayer[],
   ReplicateLayer[Automatic],
   ThreadingLayer[Exp@#1/#2 &]
   }, {NetPort@"Input" -> 1 -> 2 -> 3, {NetPort@"Input", 3} -> 4}]

ourSoftmaxLayer[{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}]
```

> ```
> {0.00440888, 0.0119846, 0.0885547, 0.240717, 0.654335}
> ```

Note that there is a small error between our softmax and the `SoftmaxLayer` output:

```
ourSoftmaxLayer[{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}] - SoftmaxLayer[]@{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}
```

> ```
> {-4.65661·10^-10, 0., -7.45058·10^-9, -1.49012·10^-8, -5.96046·10^-8}
> ```

I attribute this to some rounding errors.

We can visualize the difference between the normalization function in the question and a softmax layer:

```
BarChart[Transpose@{normalizeLayer[v], SoftmaxLayer[][v]},
   ChartLabels -> {"norm", "soft"}]
```

[image]

In a future version of Wolfram Language (perhaps 12.1), the upcoming `NetFunction` functionality may make this slightly easier, allowing you to do something along the lines of `NetFunction[u, (#/Total@u &) /@ u]`, but we shall see.

Comment: Juicy stuff here, Carl, thank you! I’m appreciative of your documentation (explanation of what your answer does). [think you can replicate the actual functionality of `SoftmaxLayer` through this method?] (I’m about to crash course my way through neural networks with mma before wss19)

Comment: @CATrevillian Glad you find it helpful! I added an implementation of the softmax function to the answer. You might also find this implementation of an `IndexMaxLayer` useful, since it has very similar mechanics: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/creating-an-indicator-function-in-a-neural-network/189410#189410